# Class instances both equal and unequal

Tags: python, python-2.7, operator-overloading, equality

What did I do wrong here? I expected instances to always be equal and never be unequal. But as it turns out, instances are both equal and unequal.

```
$ cat test.py
class MyClass(object):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = MyClass()
    b = MyClass()

    if a == b:
        print "Equal"
    if a != b:
        print "Unequal"


$ python --version
Python 2.7.6

$ python test.py
Equal
Unequal
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `!=` will not call `__eq__` and invert it.  If you want to support `!=`, then you need to implement `__ne__` also.

a and b are different objects, so the default object.`__ne__` method is called, and reports True.

Comment: Thank you, that really had me stumped.

For, I dunno, bonus information...? This appears to have changed in Python 3. `!=` **will** invert `__eq__`, meaning my test file above will behave correctly.

Comment: Yes, this has changed in Python 3.